# How link JSON object with v-show?

Tags: json, vue.js

How do map between JSON object and v-show directive?

```
<a href="#panel_1" v-show="{{ tabs.tab_1 }}">Tab 1</a>    
<a href="#panel_2" v-show="{{ tabs.tab_2 }}">Tab 2</a>
<a href="#panel_3" v-show="{{ tabs.tab_3 }}">Tab 3</a>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
        tabs: [{"tab_1": true}, {"tab_2": true}, {"tab_3": true}],
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

just write

```
<a href="#panel_1" v-show="tabs.tab_1">Tab 1</a>    
<a href="#panel_2" v-show="tabs.tab_2">Tab 2</a>
<a href="#panel_3" v-show="tabs.tab_3">Tab 3</a>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
        tabs: [{"tab_1": true}, {"tab_2": true}, {"tab_3": true}],
  }
})
```

this will automatically bind `v-show` no need to add `{{ }}` there.